# Can the SQL Case Statement fall through?

Tags: sql-server, case-statement

Is there a way to make a CASE statement in SQL fall through like the case statement in C#?  What I don't want to do is the example below but if that’s my only option I guess I'll go with it.

EXAMPLE:

```
@NewValue =
   CASE
      WHEN @MyValue = '1' THEN CAST(@MyValue AS int)
      WHEN @MyValue = '2' THEN CAST(@MyValue AS int)
      ELSE NULL
   END
```

EDIT:

I'm using SQL Server.

Comment: You can use `@MyValue IN ('1', '2')` to test for multiple values in a single case.

Comment: DECLARE @NewValue int, @MyValue varchar(50); SET @MyValue='111'; SET @NewValue=NULL; **if ISNUMERIC (@MyValue)=1** BEGIN SET @NewValue=@MyValue END; PRINT @MyValue

Comment: Mark: Your right I do want what Nate posted but I did want to know if there was to do a fall though.

Comment: I didn't post my response as an answer because, although I doubt SQL supports any kind of "fall through" or an imitation of it, I don't know for sure either way and I didn't feel like looking it up. I didn't post it as an answer because I wasn't really answering his question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To answer your specific question: No, it cannot.

See, for example, the [MySQL documentation for CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html). Every `WHEN` must have a `THEN result`, and there is no way around this. The `THEN` is not marked as optional. The same applies to all other RDBMS I've used.

Here's another example: [Sql Server's CASE expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

You already have a good alternative way to do it posted as a comment, so I won't repeat it here.

Comment: I thought only t-sql (as in sql server and sybase) used @variable syntax? but you link in mysql?

Comment: OP should mention the database they are using, otherwise everyone here is just wasting their time guessing.  picky things like this usually are DBMS specific

Comment: Added link for SQL Server too now. I'm pretty sure that my answer is not T-SQL specific, but applies to most DB. I can't say for sure if it is all - there are a lot of RDBMS, but I challenge someone to find a reasonably mainstream RDBMS that is a counter-example. ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can also do it like this:

```
@NewValue =
   CASE
      WHEN @MyValue in ( '1', '2' ) THEN CAST(@MyValue AS int)
      ELSE NULL
   END
```

or like this:

```
CASE @MyValue 
         WHEN '1' THEN CAST(@MyValue AS int)
         WHEN '2' THEN CAST(@MyValue AS int)
         ELSE null
      END
```

even though in this case the `@MyValue in ('1','2')` would make more sense.

Answer (score -2):

Could alternatively use T-SQL try-catch.  However, I'm not sure what kind of negative impact this would have on the server:

**SQL:**

```
DECLARE @intVar VARCHAR(MAX), @stringVar VARCHAR(MAX), @default_value INT, @tempVar INT
SET @default_value = NULL
SET @stringVar = 'Hello World!!'
SET @intVar = '550'

PRINT 'Casting @stringVar: '
BEGIN TRY
    SET @tempVar = CAST(@stringVar AS INT)
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SET @tempVar = @default_value
END CATCH
PRINT @tempVar + 20

PRINT ''

PRINT 'Casting @intVar: '
BEGIN TRY
    SET @tempVar = CAST(@intVar AS INT)
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SET @tempVar = @default_value
END CATCH
PRINT @tempVar
```

**Output:**
Casting @stringVar:

Casting @intVar: 
550

Furthermore, I would create user defined functions for those try catch statements that accept a varchar inputString, and int default_value, which returns the integer.