# Case statement with 'OR' statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
SELECT   ProductNumber, Category =
      CASE ProductLine
         WHEN 'R' or 'r' THEN 'Road'
         WHEN 'M' or 'm' THEN 'Mountain'
         WHEN 'T' or 't' THEN 'Touring'
         WHEN 'S' or 's' THEN 'Other sale items'
         ELSE 'Not for sale'
```

My basic requirement is to use 'OR' with CASE (if possible) , Please suggest if i am doing anything wrong.

Comment: you are missing the `END` on the `CASE` statement, but it looks fine.

Comment: I agree with bluefeet, you are simply missing `END` in your `CASE` syntax

Comment: If this list grows any longer, create another table to use as a lookup. You won't have to alter your code for each new sales item.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A different way to write `case` comes close, but then you have to repeat the variable:

```
CASE
  WHEN ProductLine in ('R', 'r') THEN 'Road'
  WHEN ProductLine in ('M', 'm') THEN 'Mountain'
```

Or a `like` character class:

```
CASE
  WHEN ProductLine like '[Rr]' THEN 'Road'
  WHEN ProductLine like '[Mm]' THEN 'Mountain'
```

Note that in SQL, string comparison is case-insensitive by default.  You can alter the default by setting a case-sensitive database collation, but that's fairly unusual.

Comment: You're also missing `END`. The syntax is `CASE WHEN [condition] THEN result [WHEN [condition] THEN result ...] [ELSE result] END `

Comment: Thanks Andomar, it seems gud and my prob will be solved if i use case in this way ... THANKS

Answer (score 0):

you can also write

```
select
    ProductNumber,
    case upper(ProductLine)
        when 'R' then 'Road'
        when 'M' then 'Mountain'
        when 'T' then 'Touring'
        when 'S' then 'Other sale items'
        else 'Not for sale'
    end as Category
```

You can set your collation to case insensitive and just compare ProductLine with letters

Comment: Thanks Roman Pekar , but my requirement will be solved if i use 'OR' with case statement as i have mentioned in the sample code, My real problem is different than i mentioned in the sample code ..

Answer (score 0):

Simply you could do as;

```
SELECT   ProductNumber, CASE LOWER(ProductLine) 
                            WHEN 'r' THEN 'Road'
                            WHEN 'm' THEN 'Mountain'
                        END AS Category
FROM TableName
```

**For more details:** [Click here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend case fall-through, but that's not allowed in SQL. However, there's a very good answer on SQL's work-around for fall-through: [Can the SQL Case Statment fall through?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120133/can-the-sql-case-statment-fall-through)